# Difference between '[Adjective] as it may sound' and 'As [adjective] as it may sound'?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference

Is there much difference between the two?

For example:

- Silly as it may sound, ...
- As silly as it may sound, ...

Also: When you say it like the second example, does the second 'as' still mean '(even) though'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Silly as it may seem, [...]
>
> As silly as it may seem, [...]

There is not much difference between the two phrases. They are almost interchangeable in many cases, and convey the same meaning in both cases. The phrase in the first case is stripped of the adverb. I am not sure if this special case is called something in English, perhaps someone else may assist you in that.

And yes, it would 'even though' in both cases. You may even rephrase your sentence like:

> Even though it may sound silly, [...]